# Textbook on group theory for physics student

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm an undergraduate physics student and realize I should learn some group theory for physics. Does anyone know any good textbooks that would be good for this? I've found the following but am not sure if any of them are good:

[Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics - Michael Tinkham](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486432475)

[Symmetry: An Introduction to Group Theory and Its Applications - Roy McWeeny](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486421821)

[A Course on Group Theory - John Rose](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486681947)

Comment: You don't need a full book on group theory.  Physicists only use certain parts of group/ representation theory ($SO(n),\ SU(n)$, etc).  Try [*Linearity, Symmetry, and Prediction in the Hydrogen Atom*](http://www.amazon.com/Linearity-Symmetry-Prediction-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387246371).  It goes over a lot of different topics in the context of that familiar thing from undergrad QM -- the Hydrogen atom.  In particular it covers all of the group theory that you'll need to know unless/ until you decide to start studying supersymmetry or string theory or something like that.

Comment: why the graph-theory tag?

Answer (score 1):

As an undergraduate physics student, I really doubt you need to delve into something as... rich as say, Dummit and Foote. I suggest Abstract Algebra by Judson. The first few chapters are on group theory. Free, open source, easy to read. Overall awesome. 
http://abstract.ups.edu/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the kind of group theory a Physics major would need. But, I learn best when the text is laced with history, anecdotes and motivation. I recommend A Book of Abstract Algebra - by Charles Pinter to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Group theory and quantum mechanics by Michael Tinkham which you mention is the standard group theory textbook on my university for undergraduate (and graduate) physics students.

I think only the last two or three of eight chapters specifically is about quantum mechanics.

I remember thinking it was a good book when i took that course 10 years ago.